# How to show an error if an input field is empty in a form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Please help. I've been stuck on the same problem for about two weeks now. So I downloaded the advanced login master script from Github and customized it a bit.

[Advanced login script](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced)

Everything was going fine until I created a Post class and tried adding an ajax form to the "views/logged_in.php" file. The form validation error messages stopped showing up correctly. I'm trying to check if the input field is empty for the form before submitting the form via Ajax. I'm not used to the way this script has been set up. The index file seems to call the classes. But when I try to add ajax it throws me off completely.

Can somebody please show me the proper way to add a simple ajax form to this script within the "views/Logged in.php" file while displaying an error message if the input field is empty?

P.S.  I want to display a PHP error, not a Javascript error. In my Post class I have an array for errors and messages.

Here is my javascript ajax code.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        $("form.ajax")[0].reset();
        console.log(response);
    }
});

return false;
});
```

website.com/views/logged_in.php

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>contact.php"` method="post" class="ajax">
                    <div class="new_post_header">
                        <div class="new_post_avatar"><img src="img/profile_pic_1.png" style="width:40px; height:40px;" /></div>
                        <textarea name="post_text" id="message" class="new_post_textarea" placeholder="Give a tip"></textarea>
                    </div><!--.new_post_header-->

                    <div id="new_post_options">
                        <div class="icon-camera post_options_icon"></div>
                        <div class="icon-camcorder post_options_icon"></div>
                        <div class="icon-tag post_options_icon"></div>

                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="post_post_button">Post</button>

                        <a class="privacy_post_option" id="post_privacy_toggle">
                            <div class="icon-earth-grid privacy_option_icon"></div>
                                Public
                            <div class="icon-more-arrow privacy_option_arrow"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div><!--#new_post_options-->
                </form><!--.ajax-->
```

website.com/classes/Post.php class

```
    <?php
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var object $db_connection The database connection
     */
    private $db_connection      = null;
    /**
     * @var string $logged_in_user_id the poster's id variable
     */
    public $logged_in_user_id   = null;
    /**
 * @var string $post_text The post text variable
 */
public $post_text           = "";
/**
 * @var array collection of error messages
 */
public  $errors             = array();
/**
 * @var array collection of success / neutral messages
 */
public  $messages           = array();

/**
 * Checks if database connection is opened and open it if not
 */
private function databaseConnection()
{
    // connection already opened
    if ($this->db_connection != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // create a database connection, using the constants from config/config.php
        try {
            // Generate a database connection, using the PDO connector
            // @see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
            // Also important: We include the charset, as leaving it out seems to be a security issue:
            // @see http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Connecting_to_MySQL says:
            // "Adding the charset to the DSN is very important for security reasons,
            // most examples you'll see around leave it out. MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE CHARSET!"
            $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            return true;
        // If an error is catched, database connection failed
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_DATABASE_ERROR;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * creates a new post in the databse
 */
public function submitPost($logged_in_user_id, $post_text)
{
    // remove extra space on post text
    $post_text  = trim($post_text);

    // if the post text is empty
    if (empty($post_text)) {
        // show the errors
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_EMPTY;
    } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        // write new post data into database
        $query_new_post_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (poster_id, post_text, post_date) VALUES(:poster_id, :post_text, NOW())');
        $query_new_post_insert->bindValue(':poster_id', $logged_in_user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query_new_post_insert->bindValue(':post_text', $post_text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_new_post_insert->execute();

        // id of new post
        $post_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

        // return the id of the last post to be added to database
        return $post_id;
    }
}

/**
 * creates a new post in the databse
 */
public function getPost($logged_in_user_id)
{
    // remove extra space on post text
    $post_text  = trim($post_text);

    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        // write new post into database
        $query_new_post_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (post_text) VALUES(:post_text)');
        $query_new_post_insert->bindValue(':post_text', $post_text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_new_post_insert->execute();

        // id of new post
        $post_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

        // return the id of the new post
        return $post_id;
    }
}
}
```

website.com/contact.php

```
  <?php
// start the seesion so that you can access the $_SESSION variable
session_start();

// put the current logged in user's id in a variable
$logged_in_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

// include the config
require_once('config/config.php');

// include the to-be-used language, english by default. feel free to translate your project and include something else
require_once('translations/en.php');

// load the post class
require_once('classes/Post.php');

// create the post object
$post = new Post(

);

if (isset($_POST['post_text'])) {
    // put the post text in a variable
    $post_text = $_POST['post_text'];

    // put the returned id from the submited post into a variable
    $post_id = $post->submitPost($logged_in_user_id, $post_text);
}
?>
```

Comment: post your code here so we can check

Comment: need html code  too

Comment: "**How to show an error if an input field is empty in a form using ajax**" - AJAX? Why AJAX?

Comment: Why not Ajax? I don't want to refresh the page. What do you recommend Jek?

Comment: hey i have added please check the answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have make your submit button as button and onclick i have called ajax function

```js
function test1()
{
var that = $('.ajax'),
    url = 'contact.php',
    type = 'POST',
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
if(value=='')
  {
    alert("please enter value of " +name);
    }
    data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
      if(response==2)
        {
          alert("plaese enter text");
           or
           $('.error').html("plaese enter text");
          
          }
        if(response==1)
          {
        $("form.ajax")[0].reset();
            }
        console.log(response);
    }
});

return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form  method="post"  class="ajax">
                    <div class="new_post_header">
                        <div class="new_post_avatar"><img src="img/profile_pic_1.png" style="width:40px; height:40px;" /></div>
                        <textarea name="post_text" id="message" class="new_post_textarea" placeholder="Give a tip"></textarea>
                    </div><!--.new_post_header-->

                    <div id="new_post_options">
                        <div class="icon-camera post_options_icon"></div>
                        <div class="icon-camcorder post_options_icon"></div>
                        <div class="icon-tag post_options_icon"></div>

                        <button  type="button" onclick="return test1();" class="post_post_button">Post</button>

                        <a class="privacy_post_option" id="post_privacy_toggle">
                            <div class="icon-earth-grid privacy_option_icon"></div>
                                Public
                            <div class="icon-more-arrow privacy_option_arrow"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div><!--#new_post_options-->
                </form><!--.ajax-->
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code works perfectly! But I wanted to call a simple PHP error not a Javascript error.  // if the post text is empty
    if (empty($post_text)) {
        // show the errors
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_EMPTY;
    }

Comment: Please refer to the Post class error array. I want to display a PHP error instead of a Javascript error.

Comment: then you if (empty($post_text)) { echo '2';exit } and on the basis of that you can print error

Comment: Would I include that in the Post.php class or in the Contact.php file?

Comment: in Contact.php only there only u r getting value

Answer (score 0):

A very simplified way of doing this would be:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var empty = true;

    $("form.ajax input").each(function(){ // check each input
        var val = $(this).val();

        if(!$.trim(val) == ""){ // if the inputs are not empty
            empty = false; // allow ajax to be submitted
        }
    });

    if(empty){
        alert("Input is empty!"); // alert that an input is empty
    } else {
        // ajax goes here
    }

    return false; // prevent form post
});
```

**Note**: This procedure also works if the `input`s contain **JUST** white space (no text). I would suggest checking for this on the server-side too, not just the client-side (as this is editable within the (potential) attackers) browser.